# Listview disable scrolling optimization

Tags: android, listview

In listview when it is scrolled, the top item which is going out of scene is attached at bottom which is coming in to scene.

Is this behaviour fixed or we can disable this feature.

In my listview, i got only 10 items so this feature is not that important to have.

Comment: I'm not sure, i understand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ignore the "**convertView**" parameter on your `Adapter.getView()`, the old view will not be used, but it will be regenerated when you scroll back.

If you don't want this behavior, use a LinearLayout.